# *pt = x; not working (meaning of * and & in C++)

Tags: c++, pointers

I am totally newbie and have hard time digesting pointer section in C++.
What I have understood is this:
to access the content of the address, use `*`
to access the address of the content, use `&`
So basically my question is this: why is the codes below throw errors?

```
int x = 10;
int *pt;
*pt = x;
```

Why should I code in formats like the below?

```
int x = 10;
int *pt;
pt = &x;
```

Also I can't understand `*pt = &x;` line. `*pt` should be the content, not the address. Why is it ok?

```
int x = 10;
int *pt = &x;
```

Similarly, to make `temp` share the same address with `n1`, I think it should be

```
int n1 = 1;
int &temp = &n1;
```

but textbook says right code is below.

```
int n1 = 1;
int &temp = n1;
```

Need HELP!

Comment: You have to be carefully: `pt = &x;`: Here, `&` is part of an _expression_ which makes it the address-operator. `int &temp = n;`: Here, `&` is part of a _declaration_ which makes it a modifier (the reference type). This is not the only case in C++. There are similar cases with `*` (in expression a dereference operator vs. in declaration a type modifier for pointer), and `=` (in expression an assignment but in declaration for initialization), to name some which popped in my mind immediately.

Comment: (1) `int *pt; *pt = x;` For this to work, you first need to assign an address of an existing variable to `pt` (so, `pt = &...;`). (2) `int *pt = &x;` this is equivalent to `int *pt; pt = &x;`, **not** to `int *pt; *pt = &x;`.

Comment: In general, a `pointer` is a variable in which its value is an address of another variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are confusing about mean of '&' and '*'.

In a nutshell,

&x: A bowl of x address.
*pt: A fork for choose address(only address).

And if you declare as 'int *pt', you don't need to declare as '*pt=&x'. Because 'pt' is already pointer variable.

Answer (score 4):

You are confusing the meaning of `*` and `&` in the expression with their meaning in variable type declaration. In variable type `*` just means that this variable is a pointer, while `&` means that it is a reference, e.g.:

```
int *pt = &x;
```

actually means "declare a pointer to `int` with name `pt` and assign the address of `x` to it". While

```
int &temp = n1;
```

means "declare a reference to `int` named `temp` and assign `n1` to it, so that `temp` refers to the same memory as `n1`".

Answer (score 0):

Pointer is a "reference to memory for particular type". In example you wrote `int *pt;` Instead try to think about it like:

```
int x = 10;

// Declare a pointer to location in memory.
// That memory is holding (or will be) value of type int.
int* pt;    

// What would be be the meaning of this? *pt doesn't really mean anything.
// int* means that it is points to type of integer
*pt = x;
```

Similar approach is for the `&x`, which is only shortcut for:

- "I know that there is variable `x` of type `int` and I would like to get address (of first byte of that int)".

```
// Again from the example, you declare int x to value 10.
int x = 10;

// Declare pointer for int type.
int* pt;

// Set pointer (variable that specifies the location in memory)
// to address of variable x (so you point "pointer pt" to location in memory
// where variable x sits
pt = &x;
```

Finally if you connect the dots:

```
int x = 10;
// 1st declare pointer of type int
// point the pointer to the value x
int* pt = &x;
```

Answer (score 0):

> why is the codes below throw errors?
>
> ```
> 1> int x = 10;
> 2> int *pt;
> 3> *pt = x;
> ```

`*pt` in line 3 accesses the `int` pointed to by `pt`, but at this time the value of `pt` is undefined.

> Why should I code in formats like the below?
>
> ```
> int x = 10;
> int *pt;
> pt = &x;
> ```

Assign *a pointer that points to `x`* to `pt`, so now the pointer `pt` points to `x`.

> Also i can't understand *pt = &x; line. *pt should be the content, not
> the address. Why is it ok?
>
> ```
> int x = 10;
> int *pt = &x;
> ```

No, `pt` is a variable and `int *` is its type. This code has the same meaning as the previous one.

> Similarly, to make temp share the same address with n1, i think it
> should be
>
> ```
> int n1 = 1;
> int &temp = &n1;
> ```
>
> but textbook says right code is below.
>
> ```
> int n1 = 1;
> int &temp = n1;
> ```

`int &` is a C++ reference type, it is not a pointer, so the `&` operator is not needed to get the address of `n1`. At this time `pt` is already binded to `n1`.